# Unable to re-open MAUI project in Visual Studio 2022 (not preview)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I installed the new release of **Visual Studio 2022 (not preview)** available since yesterday. I also installed MAUI workload from a command prompt

```
dotnet workload install maui
```

[image]

I can create a new project and choosing the .Net MAUI App (Preview)

[image]

I see the solution and all the files inside.

[image]

I can compile the solution successfully.

If I close then re-open the solution it failed.

[image]

I don'have problems for a simple Console App project. So the problem seems to be related to MAUI templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, the new Visual Studio 2022 (released november 8th 2021) does not allows us to play with MAUI templates. We will have to wait until second quarter of 2022 (I think) to get an update.

The alternative is to still use the **Visual Studio 2022 Preview edition** which allows us to use MAUI templates pretty well.

Comment: Where did you get this information and is there any official source for this?

Comment: @germi honestly I can't remember where I got this info.

Comment: Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/621569/net-maui-is-not-in-visual-studio-2022.html I asked Microsoft support this question and they said that .net maui will come to visual studio 2022 in the second quarter of 2022, so this is not possible in the curent version, but in the preview version of visual studio 2022 we can use maui preview .net

Comment: I'm finding that the VS2022 preview can no longer be used, so this answer is possibly no longer correct.

Comment: I can confirm the VS2022 Preview edition is still working nice with MAUI. Are you having problems ? Can you tell us more ?

Comment: @Bronzato Yeah, when running the preview version it no longer allows the IDE to be run. Are you doing something specific to get around that, are you running an early version that possibly didn't have the check, or are you doing stuff from the command line?

Comment: My version is Visual Studio 2022 Preview 17.1 Preview 1.1. Please note that I didn't updated manually MAUI because I read somewhere this is not yet 100% compatible with the current VS 2022 Preview version. So my MAUI is still preview 10. What are your versions (VS & MAUI) ?

Answer (score -1):

As today the same thing happened to me, try to install the visual studio 2022 preview version; it's  working and you find .Net MAUI here:

[image]